# azure ad user provisioning with g suite

Tags: google-cloud-platform, azure-active-directory, google-workspace

We have integrated G suite with Azure AD as an enterprise app and which supports SAML. We are also enabling auto user provisioning means If a user is added on the Azure enterprise app then it should be provisioned on google suite app via auto user provisioned. Now we have added many groups and users but few of them facing this issue. It seems to me azure ad sending the user to google app however when the request reaches to Google suite app they reject it although we have checked request and found it did not reach to google app and throwing an error ?

"Not Authorized to access this resource/api" } ], "code": 403, "message": "Not Authorized to access this resource/api" } } Web Response: { "error": { "errors": [ { "domain": "global", "reason": "forbidden", "message": "Not Authorized to access this resource/api" } ], "code": 403, "message": "Not Authorized to access this resource/api" } } . This operation was retried 0 times. It will be retried again after this date:

Comment: Edit your question and include specific details on the task you are performing. Your question as written means you have a permission problem, but the details are missing on what caused the error, how you have integrated G Suite with AAD, etc.

Comment: Hi John, I hope you can see details, it is SAML app and configured as enterprise gallery app .. please let me know If you have further queries

Comment: Did you configure automatic user provisioning to G Suite? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/saas-apps/google-apps-provisioning-tutorial#configuring-automatic-user-provisioning-to-g-suite

Comment: Hi John, Yes it is configured, everything is working as expected however only few users are facing this. G Suite team is saying that request is not reaching to them and on Azure, we do not have much info to get an idea of what it could be?

Comment: @JohnHanley, now we also see below error for few users but not much information on Azure audit logs that says why they are getting skipped?

Details details: Skip reason = UnableToResolveReferenceAttributeValue, Active = ?, Assigned = ?, Passed scope filter: ?;

Comment: Yes and also opened case with Vendor but It seems a bug

Comment: We break apart some operations into multiple pieces if we need to do additional work before we know what value to send to the other side (Gsuite, in this case). This error means that we were trying to resolve a reference to another object and failed to do so.

Comment: The other attributes about this user were likely successfully processed in another operation, while this split off operation failed. The most likely cause here is that the user's manager is not in scope for provisioning and when the provisioning service went to go translate the user's manager in AAD (referred to as ObjectID) into whatever identifier that Gsuite requires a manager to be referred to with, we were unable to find the user's manager provisioned to Gsuite and therefore failed to successfully translate(ie: resolve) the manager reference

Comment: thanks, Nishant, but it seems Azure AD does not trigger API to Gsuite update group membership update for some users, we did try on-demand for few users who were facing the issue and it fixed the issue. Having said that, it's not done automatically as supposed to