# AzureAD Google Cloud Connector user provisioning failure

Tags: google-cloud-platform, azure-active-directory, google-workspace

While testing automated user/group provisioning with the AzureAD Google Cloud EA, I am seeing a number of HTTP 403 errors at the Scoping phase of the user provisioning process that look like below:

**Description**: Failed to evaluate scoping of a source entry User 'user@foobar.com'

**Error Code**:   GoogleAppsCannotAccessResourceOrApi

**Error Message**: An error has occurred when our provisioning service tried to evaluate scoping of a source entry.

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Not Authorized to access this resource/api",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Not Authorized to access this resource/api",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "forbidden"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

To note: This issue affects many users but not all of them.  Many more are successfully provisioned.

Also, to note: There are no scoping filters in place (source scope is "All records").

This looks similar to [azure ad user provisioning with g suite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61504301/azure-ad-user-provisioning-with-g-suite) but that question hasn't been answered and I tried removing the user's manager from the attribute mapping (as implied in the last response) but no luck.

Comment: Do you have the right permissions on your account to execute that method? I would recommend you try their console here: developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/admin/directory_v1/… -- that way, you can see a verbose and easy to understand explanation of why you're getting a 403.

Comment: The AAD EA is given the credentials of a user with superuser rights to the G Suite Account (this is a test/eval account to validate this process)   As I said, some users (and most groups) are created without an issue.  Also, the error is not thrown at the provisioning phase, but rather the scoping phase.  The above unfortunately does not indicate if the 403 is coming from an internal Azure API or a G Suite API.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out the issue.  First, it turns out that the problem has nothing to do with scoping, regardless of what the provisioning logs were saying.

My problem was that I perform a [custom attribute re-mapping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/app-provisioning/customize-application-attributes) of the users UPN, as G Suite is configured for another domain and that I forgot that we have a mishmash of upper and lower case domain names in our users' UPNs.

My [expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/app-provisioning/functions-for-customizing-application-data) failed to normalize the UPNs to lowercase before performing a case-sensitive replacement for the old domain to the new domain.  Once I added a ToLower expression, the scoping errors went away.